# Synonym proposal: [cp-sat] -> [cp-sat-solver]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

All [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat) questions have the [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver) tag.

We don't have enough users who are able to vote:
https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cp-sat-solver/topusers

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cp-sat-solver/synonyms

Comment: As there's only 23 questions, it would be better to have community consensus and just remove the tag from the questions, it seems. At least one other [person agrees](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77061082/revisions) with you, as the tag usage guidance states *"Duplicate of the cp-sat-solver tag. Please use the cp-sat-solver tag."*

Comment: These are the same tag in usage as well as meaning [\[cp-sat\] -\[cp-sat-solver\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat%2b-cp-sat-solver?tab=Newest) gives 0 results (even including deleted posts).

Comment: I second removing the tag. I can merge and delete [cp-sat] (or [cp-sat-solver]) so we don't have to bump anything with edits, I'll wait a bit to see if there are any objections since that can't be undone.

Comment: I tried. I manually changed all of them. It keeps popping up.

Comment: Actually, I would like to merge cp-sat-solver into cp-sat as this is the name of the corresponding tag on or.stackexchange.com. One can dream ::-)

Comment: Yes please merge [cp-sat-solver] into [cp-sat] instead @HenryEcker hopefully being shorter will make it easer to canonicalize, so that the removed one does not pop up again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This required two steps to keep the useful tag wiki excerpt information from [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver).

1. Merge [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat) -> [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver); No synonym created

```
updating post history, 29 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 23 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 0 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'cp-sat': [cp-sat] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Announcement had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 history records for type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Collectives Discussion had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 135
tag remapping of [cp-sat-solver] and [cp-sat] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
2 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
```

This deleted [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat) and since all [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat) questions also had the [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver) tag this did not affect the total number of [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver) questions.

This cannot be undone, though it was essentially a duplicate tag.

---

2. Rename [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver) -> [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat); Synonym created.

```
updating post history, 152 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 135 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
Target tag 'cp-sat' doesn't exist, renaming 'cp-sat-solver' to 'cp-sat'
rename result: 1 rows affected
tag remapping of [cp-sat] and [cp-sat-solver] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
17 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
16 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym cp-sat-solver -> cp-sat was approved!
```

This will take a little bit to settle, but once it does the tag is [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat) and has the tag wiki excerpt history from [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver). All future uses of [cp-sat-solver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat-solver) will be automatically remapped to [cp-sat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cp-sat).

The tag can easily be renamed back in future if needed.